# Telepresence with SSH Tunnel for Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, telepresence

I have a remote privately managed Kubernetes cluster that I reach by going via an intermediary VM. To use kubectl from my machine I have setup an SSH tunnel that hops onto my VM and then onto my master node - this works fine.

I am trying to configure Telepresence (https://www.telepresence.io/) which attempts to start up (correctly detecting that kubectl works) but then fails due to a timeout.

```
subprocess.TimeoutExpired: Command '['ssh', '-F', '/dev/null', '-oStrictHostKeyChecking=no', '-oUserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null', '-q', '-p', '65367', 'telepresence@127.0.0.1', '/bin/true']' timed out after 5 seconds
```

Is this a setup that telepresence should support or is the presence of an intermediary VM going to be a roadblock for me?

Comment: Did you solve this? I am trying to do the same thing.

Comment: Unfortunately I still don't have a solution to this.

Answer (score 2):

Telepresence 2 should support this better as it installs a sidecar container that makes it more resilient to interrupted connections. I would give the new version a try to see if you're still seeing timeout errors.

https://www.getambassador.io/docs/latest/telepresence/quick-start/